# In Postgres - when transaction IDs wraparound what are their numbers?

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 11, when transaction IDs pass the 4 billion wraparound mark, assuming that the database is properly autovacuumed, what will be the next txid returned by txid_current()?

Will the returned transaction IDs start again from 1 or will they continue to have IDs greater than 4 billion and the txid_current() will return numbers greater than 4 billion.

The documentation says "... these functions export a 64-bit format that is extended with an “epoch” counter so it will not wrap around during the life of an installation."  So my understanding is that txid_current() returns bigint and the the returned txid will not start from zero. postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-info.html

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND) state that

> the XID counter wraps around to zero

Comment: This not what I red. "the XID counter wraps around to zero...which means their output become invisible. In short, catastrophic data loss... To avoid this, it is necessary to vacuum every table in every database at least once every two billion transactions."

Comment: Your question is, what is the next number when it wraps around. The link above, specifically the quoted part, answers that it wraps around to zero. Am I missing something?

Comment: The page you indicated says "to avoid this, it is necessary to vacuum every table in every database at least once every two billion transactions" So this means that if the database is vacuumed it can be avoided. Does it mean that transaction IDs won't wrap around and or does it mean that txids will wrap around bur there will be no data loss.